# I'm getting this error in flutter for androidmanifest.xml Missing 'name' key attribute on element uses-permission at AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, flutter

this is my androidmanifest.xml

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="authsec_flutter"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

Missing 'name' key attribute on element uses-permission at AndroidManifest.xml, i was trying to add icon for my flutter app , i installed flutter_launcher_icons, ive even replaced my older androidmanifest.xml file , still same error

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml
use this :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

use this before your <applicatioon....

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `name` param and instead of `name` use `label` for application name

```
<application
       android:label="Test Application"
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
       android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
       android:largeHeap="true" ........ />
```